# Finding a ruby hash value in an SQL statement search

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, hashmap

I am using datatables and they are built in with a search feature. I am trying to find and return all IPs where any column in the ips table is LIKE :search (params[:sSearch). The code is as follows:

```
 def fetch_ips
    ips = Ip.order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")
    ips = ips.page(page).per_page(per_page)
    if params[:sSearch].present?
      ips = ips.where("ip_address LIKE :search OR system_name LIKE :search OR description LIKE :search OR system_location LIKE :search OR status LIKE :search", search: "%#{params[:sSearch]}%")
 end
```

This action will decide what 'ips' is and i will later return 'ips' (but for now that's not valid).
The problem I am having is that where the code in this statement says "status LIKE :search" (status being a number), you have to search the number in the search bar whereas I want the user to be able to search the description.

To clarify, I have a hash that basically maps the statuses 0 - 3 to a description. The description is the value in the hash and the number is the key as the number is stored in the database.

```
STATUSES = { 0 => "Unallocated",
           1 => "Allocated",
           2 => "Reserved",
           3 => "Transient"
 }
```

How would I allow the user to search the for value of 'status' rather than having to search for the status key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
search = "%#{params[:sSearch]}%"
status = STATUSES.key(search.titleize) || ""
```

The 'titleize' will upcase the first letter and downcase the rest. The empty string is necessary because it will return 0 matches when matched with an integer column; otherwise records with nil status will be matched.

Then:

```
# reducing the number of columns in this example

ips = ips.where("
                  ip_address LIKE :search OR
                  system_name LIKE :search OR
                  status = :status
                ", {
                  search: search,
                  status: status
               })
```

Also, just FYI, you're missing an 'end' in your code.

Comment: I am trying to allow the user to search 'unallocated' and all of the ip's with a status of 0 be returned, I don't want them to have to search '0' to get all the unallocated IPs as this would conflict with a search for an ip_address as most of them contain numbers 0 - 3

Comment: the line of code "status = Ip::STATUSES.key(search.titleize) ||= '' " constantly returns nothing unless i take out the ||= "", also for some reason the ips will not filter when i search for a certain status. I changed the code a bit to better debug it, now the line of code is like this "ips = ips.where("status = :status", status: status)" but this still does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Obviously, the status variable will be set to "" unless the search string is a value within the STATUSES hash. Retry it with a valid status value such as "allocated". And there's no "||=" - there's just a "||"

Comment: To fix it, I changed search.titleize to params[:sSearch].titelize as the percentages and #{} was causing bugs. I now have an issue with the search as it's not searching for anything else properly, but you have given me the answer I need in regards to how to search for a value to a key stored in the database. Thank you for your help.